# combine ACLs in use_backend statement

Tags: haproxy

I want to combine 2 different types of acl in haproxy (`src` and `path_beg`) to make a decision about which backend to use.

I tried the following which is **not** valid syntax:

```
acl my_ip src 192.168.0.50
acl api_path path_beg /api
use_backend private_backend if my_ip AND api_path
use_backend public_backend if api_path
```

The `AND` in the 3rd line does not work.

I've also tried the following which is **not** valid syntax:

```
acl my_ip_and_api_path src 192.168.0.50 path_beg /api
```

Using `path_beg` after the `src` and the IP doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please make sure that the IP address you are connecting from is indeed the mentioned 192.168.0.50 and it's better to note single IP's with a /32 range.
Also, remove the AND in the if statement. It is implicit and is known to cause some invalid syntax in some cases if used.
So a working configuration for you should be:

```
acl my_ip src 192.168.0.50/32
acl api_path path_beg /api
use_backend private_backend if my_ip api_path
use_backend public_backend if api_path
```